# Retrieve external command output in Julia

Tags: julia

The system command 'stty size' returns two integers which give the dimension of the current terminal. How can Julia execute this command and return the outputs in two integer variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a pipeline and redirect `stdout` to a buffer, and then parse the string:

```
julia> io = IOBuffer();

julia> cmd = pipeline(`stty size`; stdout=io, stderr=devnull);

julia> run(cmd);

julia> str = String(take!(io))
"60 211\n"

julia> a, b = parse.(Int, split(strip(str)));

julia> a
60

julia> b
211
```

---

*Note*: Normally one can just `read` the command directly, e.g. `` read(`stty size`), String) ``, but for this particular command it does not seem to work, *I think* this is because a proper tty is not set up in that case):

```
julia> read(`stty size`, String)
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: Perfect ! I also tried without success : read(`stty size`, String).  Thank you